# postgresql showing huge sort in explain

Tags: postgresql

I have a rather simple query that is taking a lot of time. when I do an explain analyze it is showing a massive sort, that I don't know where it's coming from. The sort is taking 88% of the time but I don't understand why it's there and how to remove it.

The query is:

```
explain analyze SELECT DISTINCT "holidays".* 
    FROM "holidays" 
    join periods on 
        holidays.id = periods.holiday_id 
        WHERE 
            (periods.duration_nights >= 5 AND
            periods.duration_nights <= 32 AND
            periods.price >= 100 AND
            periods.price <= 3800 ) 
    LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0;
```

The explain result is below:

```
"Limit  (cost=825252.03..825253.35 rows=12 width=6699) (actual time=3264.827..3268.273 rows=12 loops=1)"
"  ->  Unique  (cost=825252.03..832958.41 rows=70058 width=6699) (actual time=3264.824..3268.268 rows=12 loops=1)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=825252.03..825427.17 rows=70058 width=6699) (actual time=3264.822..3265.161 rows=441 loops=1)"
"              Sort Key: holidays.id, holidays.product_id, holidays.name, holidays.price, holidays.url, holidays.description, holidays.category, holidays.country, holidays.region, holidays.city, holidays.latitude, holidays.longitude, holidays.service_type, holidays.accommodation_type, holidays.accommodation_code, holidays.accommodation_name, holidays.stars, holidays.rating, holidays.group_holiday, holidays.transport_type, holidays.airline, holidays.departure_airport, holidays.price_unit, holidays.booking_url, holidays.target_group, holidays.tour_operator, holidays.tour_operator_category, holidays.has_pool, holidays.distance_beach, holidays.distance_supermarket, holidays.distance_village, holidays.distance_airport, holidays.created_at, holidays.updated_at, holidays.distance_restaurant, holidays.image, holidays.has_wifi, holidays.has_kids_pool, holidays.has_day_care, holidays.has_supermarket, holidays.has_bar, holidays.has_restaurant, holidays.has_parking"
"              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 70784kB"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=3027.75..14081.67 rows=70058 width=6699) (actual time=13.708..315.283 rows=70734 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: (periods.holiday_id = holidays.id)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on periods  (cost=0.00..6996.62 rows=70058 width=4) (actual time=0.011..108.429 rows=70734 loops=1)"
"                          Filter: ((duration_nights >= 5) AND (duration_nights <= 32) AND (price >= 100::numeric) AND (price <= 3800::numeric))"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 51597"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=443.00..443.00 rows=3100 width=6699) (actual time=7.605..7.605 rows=3100 loops=1)"
"                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 32  Memory Usage: 116kB"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on holidays  (cost=0.00..443.00 rows=3100 width=6699) (actual time=0.002..1.013 rows=3100 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 4497.170 ms"
```

Comment: Why do you apply the distinct at all? A distinct on all columns of a table is usually code smell. You are not selecting any column from the `periods` table, so a join isn't necessary. Try with a co-related subquery and an `EXISTS` operator. That will make the distinct unnecessary (and with an index on `periods(holiday_id, duration_night, price)` this might be substantially faster

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're fantastic! I would never have tried this without your advice and the result is that is went down from 5108ms to 17ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sort is there because of the distinct operator.

To compute distinct elements in a set, you need to check for dups.

The fast way to check for dups in a set is to sort rows by all columns that you're selecting, and compare, for each row, columns one by one with the same column of the previous row. If a column is a mismatch, it's not a dup. If all columns are identical, it is a dup of the previous row. Iterate, rinse, repeat.

The reason it's slow is because it's sorting on disk. Increase your [work_mem](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM) and the swapping should go away.

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server